# Constraints on Vector Space and Dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I use the rank-nullity theorem to show that if $$V =\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}: a+b+c = 0, a+2b+3c =0\right\}$$ then $\dim($V$) = 2?$

I don't see how the theorem ban be applied to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I assume you meant $a+b+c=0$ instead of $x+y+z=0$, and same for the other equation.

Write a matrix with the first two rows [1, 1, 1, 0] and [1, 2, 3, 0].  Then complete the matrix to a nonsingular matrix.  The remaining two rows will give you the basis of the solution set to this equation.

The rank-nullity theorem tells you that you started with 4 unknowns, and thus your Dim = 4.  Also, the 2 constraints you have tell you which vectors will go to zero, and thus determine your nullspace.  Then rk + NS = Dim translates to rk + 2 = 4, so the rank of your solution set will be 4 - 2 = 2.

Comment: What role does the rank nullity theorem play, as it was specified in the problem?

Comment: I updated my answer; let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: How does that follow from the rank nullity theorem, that rank(A) + null(A) = number of columns? Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Sorry for the unclearness, I really should be going to sleep now.  Let me know if the updated version explains it, so I can explain this to you well and go.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's actually not correct.  If you complete the matrix to something nonsingular, there is no null space, so you can't say anything about $V$.

Comment: @MichaelHarrison No, the point is, the rank-nullity theorem would apply not to the completed matrix itself, but to the completed matrix with the first two rows replaced by zeros (since those two vectors would map to zero anyways).

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense, that's not how I interpreted your response

Comment: @MichaelHarrison As I told the OP, it's really late here, and I should be long asleep, thus the quality of my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 0
\end{array} \right).
$$

This matrix has rank $2$, note that the bottom two rows are linearly dependent (they are repeats of the top two rows).  Moreover, any vector in $V$ is in the null space, by your definition of $V$.  Therefore, the rank-nullity theorem says that dim$(V) = 4 - \operatorname{rank}(A) = 4 - 2 = 2$.